# NPM packages in CodePen using "Import" leads to issues

Tags: javascript, npm, codepen

I'm using NPM packages in CodePen using import and wanted to use g-i-s which scrapes Google Images for images. By importing it, it stopped my code entirely.
Tried many steps but in vain. Here's my code sample.

```
import gIS from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/pin/g-i-s@v2.1.6-znGaQm9AKRuXeOL9Ol9V/mode=imports/optimized/g-i-s.js'

console.log("LOADED IMPORT")

gIS('cats', async function (err, results) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("FUNC ERR: "+err)
    return
  }
  console.log(results[1].url)
})
```

Please help!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. If you have an error, show us the error. Give us as much information as you can. What have you done? What was your output? , ...

Comment: There wasn't any output. No errors.

Comment: [Here another URL](https://www.skypack.dev/view/g-i-s) is used for the CDN version; have you tried that? Weird thing is that you don't get any kind of error. If loading is failing, you should be able to tell.

Comment: That's the one I was using. Also used the two production URL's you can find by going to the link inside the HTML example at the top of the page, same results.

Comment: EDIT: Actually I'm using one of the production versions. As I said above, I had the same results for each of the production URL's as the main one, so I doubt it would be the cause.